# How do i bounce seperate rectangles with list of different coordinates for different Rect Obj in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So, What I want is to move every rectangle.
This program is moving the rectangle but some of them don't even touch the bottom, left, right or top It's like only one is deciding their movement. How to I change it to move different from other rectangles
Here is my code

```py
import pygame
from random import randint
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
running = True
dx = 0.1
dy = 0.1
rt = []
for i in range(5):
    x = randint(0, 500)
    y = randint(0, 400)
    rt.append([x, y])

def draw_rec(x, y):
    r = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 30)  # startx, starty, width, height
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), r)


while running:
    screen.fill((0, 145, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for i in range(5):
        x = rt[i][0]
        y = rt[i][1]

        if x < 470:
            x += dx
        else:
            dx = -0.1
            x += dx

        if y < 370:
            y += dy
        else:
            dy = -0.1
            y += dy

        if x < 1:
            dx = 0.1
        if y < 1:
            dy = 0.1

        draw_rec(x, y)
        rt[i][0] = x
        rt[i][1] = y

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rectangle moves in its own direction. Therefore 1 direction vector (`dx`, `dy`) is not sufficient. You need a separate direction vector for each rectangle. Remove `dx` and `dy`, but add a list of direction vectors.

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from random import randint
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
running = True

d = []
rt = []
for i in range(5):
    x = randint(0, 500)
    y = randint(0, 400)
    rt.append([x, y])
    d.append([0.1, 0.1])

def draw_rec(x, y):
    r = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 30)  # startx, starty, width, height
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), r)


while running:
    screen.fill((0, 145, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for i in range(5):
        x = rt[i][0]
        y = rt[i][1]

        if x < 470:
            x += d[i][0]
        else:
            d[i][0] = -0.1
            x += d[i][0]

        if y < 370:
            y += d[i][1]
        else:
            d[i][1] = -0.1
            y += d[i][1]

        if x < 1:
            d[i][0] = 0.1
        if y < 1:
            d[i][1] = 0.1

        draw_rec(x, y)
        rt[i][0] = x
        rt[i][1] = y

    pygame.display.update()
```